# how to map ?1 through to ?n

Tags: function, netlogo

I am creating an overarching reporter (consisting of a couple reporters) which I would like to operate on all the turtles within a single turtle’s neighbourhood.

It is as follows:
(((function1 neighbour1 * function2 neighbour1) + (function1 neighbour2 * function2 neighbour2) + (function1 neighbour3 * function2 neighbour3)…………)) / (function1 neighbour1 + function1 neighbour2 + function1 neighbour2........)) all the way to however many neighbours are found within the single turtle's neighbourhood.

From the reading of posts, I think the map primitive may be the most helpful here. The trouble I am having however, is that I do not know how to write ?1 through to ?n.

All I know is that ?n differs depending on how many turtles wander into that neighbourhood (e.g. sometimes I have 4 neighbours, then 7, then 1 etc.)

Please, if anyone knows how to write 1?......n? and could advise me, or direct me to some relevant information please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Richard, I assume you mean the tag [tag:turtle-graphics] instead of [tag:turtle], correct? If yes, please [edit] your question and retag it :)

Comment: Hello Unor. Sorry, I meant turtle procedures in Netlogo. I will retag now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how the neighbors stored. If they were in a list, you'd want `map`. But I'll suppose they're stored in an agentset, since it's idiomatic in NetLogo to use agentsets whenever possible.

You mentioned `map`. Normally with agentsets you don't need `map`; you just use `of`.

Supposing the turtle has its neighbor turtles stored in an agentset called `my-neighbors`, then you write:

```
sum [function1 self * function2 self] of my-neighbors
```

That's assuming that `function1` and `function2` are procedures that expect an agent as an input. If they're no-input procedures, that simply are intended to be run by a certain agent, then the code is even simpler:

```
sum [function1 * function2] of my-neighbors
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry, for not mentioning. I stored my neighbours as an agent-set using                                                     let neighbours turtle-set other turtles in-radius neighbourhood

Comment: I just tried your very helpful sum [function1 * function2] of my-neighbours, but I received an error saying that it expected input to be a number but got a list. I'll keep working on it now thank you.

Comment: *what* expected input to be a number? map or something else. it matters. Also, you don't need to use turtle-set on "other turtles in-radius neighbourhood" in-radius and other both return agentsets. it always helps to be very clear on what is expected and returned by the inputs and outputs of the reporters you are using.

Comment: Hello again all. Seth was absolutely right. I have been storing my neighbours as an agentset and my procedures expect an agent as an input. However, I don't think I wrote my formula correctly as the function actually expects two agents. A more correct version would be

Comment: (((function1 [myself neighbour1] * function2 [myself neighbour1]) + (function1 [myself neighbour2] * function2 [myself neighbour2]) + (function1 [myself neighbour3] * function2 [myself neighbour3])…………)) / (function1 [myself neighbour1] + function1 [myself neighbour2] + function1 [myself neighbour2]........))

Comment: Apologies to TurtleZero, I should have been clearer with the error that I received.   I am trying to achieve this using the code    
let topformula sum ([func1 myself self] of neighbours) * ([func2 myself self] of neighbours)  but I receive an error    * expected input to be a number but got the list [0.16000000000000003 0.5000000000000001] instead.
error while turtle 2 running *
  called by procedure FIND-PROTO
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'

Comment: Additionally, thank you both for your helpful comments

Comment: Apparently `func1` and `func2` is returning a list, and then you're trying to use * to multiply a list, which doesn't make sense. This gives the same error for the same reason: `let l1 [1 2] let l2 [3 4] print l1 * l2`

Comment: Hello Seth. Thank you for your example. I have looked into my code and it seems to be making lists when I don't mean it to. I was hoping for my reporter to (function1 [myself neighbour1] * function2 [myself neighbour1]) + (function1 [myself neighbour2] * function2 [myself neighbour2]).....through all neighbours.    But instead my code seems to be making a list of (function1 * [myself AllNeighboursOneByOne] and trying to add this to another list of (function2 * [myself AllNeighboursOneByOne]. As a result I am receiving a multiplying list error as mentioned above.

Comment: Is perhaps my code (sum [func1 myself self] of neighbours) * ( sum [func2 myself self] of neighbours) the wrong approach? I've tried varying this code in different ways but with no success. I really appreciate all of your help. Thank you

Comment: I suggest you open a new question and show your current code. Your original question has, in my opinion, been answered.

Comment: You may need to show the code for `func1` and `func2`, since the problem might be there. As I wrote earlier, "apparently func1 and func2 [are] returning a list"; if that isn't what you intended them to return, then perhaps the problem is in those functions, rather than here.

Comment: Thank you Seth. I agree that this post is becoming a bit long-winded and off the original topic. I will repost a new question now as clearly and succinctly as possible and with additional code. Thanks again for everything